# Check root element FIELD for existence in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having a trouble checking root (`_source`) field for existence.
The problem in short is that I am having an object in `_source` that might have this field too and ES returns the hit for both (field exists in `_source` and field exists in `_source.myobject`)

Imagine a document that looks like:

```
{
  "_index": "someIndex",
  "_type": "someType",
  "_id": "someId",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {

    "foo": 1,

    "myobject": {

      "foo": 1,

      "bar": 1
    }
  }
}
```

In ideal case I would like to **NOT** return this document when checking for existence of `bar`.

But my simple filter does return this document:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

So, is it possible to access **just** the root field key by a similar syntax as accessing `myobject`'s field (`"field": "myobject.bar"`).

Test it yourself:

```
POST /test-index/foo
{
    "bar": ["1", "2"],
    "myobject": {
        "baz": ["1", "2"]
    }
}

POST /test-index/foo/_search
{
    "filter": {
        "exists": {
           "field": "baz"
        }
    }
}
```

The above query is returning the document, I would like a filter that doesn't.

Thank you very much

Comment: what is the `type` of myobject? is it nested?

Comment: To be honest, not sure (sorry our infrastructure is quite big) `_mapping` says it's a property with another properties so I suspect it's just an object

Comment: your query is working fine for me on ES 1.7 and ES 2.0, it does **not** return the document

Comment: Just checking on 1.7 and the query doesn't work (returning a result when it shouldn't). Basically my filter returning the document when filtering the field "bar"

Comment: Ok, this was fixed in 2.2.0 (probably earlier but 1.7.0 still has the issue and 2.2.0 doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be fixed in higher version of ES.
1.6.0 and 1.7.0 has this problem and when tried 2.2.0 it works as expected.